# Move print jobs in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, printing, cups, sonoma

Every version of macOS I've used has allowed me to open the print queue and drag a print job from one printer to another queue. This is especially helpful when (for example) you accidentally send a job to a printer that is offline or unavailable. Today I tried to print, macOS defaulted to the last used printer, which was in my workplace. I tried to move the print job to my home printer, but the Print Center doesn't allow anything other than pausing or canceling the job. I don't see anything obvious in the CUPS interface. I don't have to do this often, but it's truly obnoxious to see a functional system dialog be replaced with one that doesn't have anywhere near the same features. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes, it looks like they haven't implemented this in the new app. Make sure you submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: Submitted as a bug report. Technically, it's a regression - feature that no longer works...

Answer (score 5):

As you'll likely already found yourself, this is a regression and moving jobs between queues using the UI is not implemented (yet).

However, [this Apple Discussions post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255335780?answerId=260192062022&sortBy=best#260192062022) suggests that you can still move jobs using the command line (links to manpages added by me):

> - Open Terminal
> - Run [`lpstat`](https://ss64.com/mac/lpstat.html) to find the print jobs

For me this looks like this:

```
➜ lpstat  
EPSON_XP_640_Series-32  user       311296   Tue Feb 27 13:09:45 2024
```

> - For each print job listed ("foobar_printer-XXX" where the name of the printer is "foobar_printer", and the print job is "XXX"), run [`lpmove`](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpmove.html)`XXX new_printer`.

If I would've had another printer named e.g. "HP_LaserJet_M402dn" I would then run the command:

```
lpmove 32 HP_LaserJet_M402dn
```

As can be seen on the `lpmove` man page, you can also move all jobs from one printer to the other, e.g. in my case:

```
lpmove EPSON_XP_640_Series HP_LaserJet_M402dn
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be turned into a script that moves all pending jobs to one given printer. You could then have Shortcut workflows or Automator apps that incorporated them.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Shortcut/Automator, but the [`lpmove`](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpmove.html) command can move all jobs from one printer to the other: `lpmove source_printer destination_printer`.

Comment: For the first example, `lpmove EPSON_XP_640_Series-32 HP_LaserJet_M402dn` should also work (according to the man page).

Comment: This worked well for me, the name of the printer is the name with spaces turned into _.  Thanks for the quick tip.